# Is it possible to make an interface method return the type of another method with a generic type parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, httpclient, fluent

So I'm trying to create some fluent code to execute a web request. I want it to look something like this...

```
// Result should be of type MyClass
var result = await _webRequests.Get("Api/Route/Here")
                               .Returns<MyClass>()
                               .HasToken("MY_TOKEN")
                               .ExecuteAsync();

// Result should be of type HttpResponseMessage
var result = await _webRequests.Get("Api/Route/Here")
                               .HasToken("MY_TOKEN")
                               .ExecuteAsync();
```

I'm aiming to get it so that if the Returns method is not specified, then it returns a HttpResponseMessage and if it is specified, it returns the type specified.

*_webRequests* is an interface with some basic HttpMethod calls in there

```
IUseRequired Get(string url);
IUseRequired Post(string url);
```

Then the *IUseRequired* interface has the required methods for the call...

```
IUseOptionalOrExecute UsesApi(string apiName);
```

All the *UsesApi* method does is tell which HTTPClient to use when using IHttpClientFactory.

Now the *IUseOptionalOrExecute* interface is where the problem starts...

```
IUseOptionalOrExecute Returns<TReturn>();
IUseOptionalOrExecute HasToken(string token);
Task<TReturn> ExecuteAsync();
```

I want it to look something like this, so whatever is passed in to the *Returns* method will be used as the return of the *ExecuteAsync* method. Of course this doesn't work, because *ExecuteAsync* has no idea what **TReturn** is. I've thought about storing the type as a variable when the *Returns* method is called, but I can't set the return type of *Execute* to be a variable type. Or can I?
Anyone know a way I can get around this? Thanks!

Comment: As mcc points out, there is a way, but it means you have to create a whole new generic type, and possibly end up with an exploding API once you deal with all the possibilities (e.g. do you try to prevent people being able to call `Returns` a second time with a different type?). Pay careful attention to _reasons for change_ and make sure your coupling choices reflect those reasons. Do you really want to have to provide the token separately for each method call, as opposed to using a service that adds a given token to every request automatically? And why are you trying to write your own library?

Comment: We are trying to use libraries in our company that others can call so they can use a few lines of code compared to writing huge chunks each time. A setup is better like this so we don't get everyone using their own way of accessing API's and code starts to look similar and easier to debug for everyone. I do agree setting the token automatically would be better though that's difficult and messy with a generic library. Also there may be endpoints that require a token and others don't so changing it on the fly would be needed anyway.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend looking at other libraries that are written for the same purpose. For example, if you use RestSharp, you wouldn't have to spend your time creating a fluent API for building requests, and you could focus more on building factories and wrappers that focus on what's specific to your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a good reason for the existence of the `Returns<TReturn>` function ?

When I implemented my HTTP client I had the return type specified on the `ExecuteAsync<TReturn>`, since there was no need to know the type beforehand and thus I avoided solving you issue.

If you need the type for some reason, I think you might need to do `IUseOptionalOrExecute<TReturn> Returns<TReturn>();` and deal with all the necessary complications.

I can expand on that if `ExecuteAsync<TReturn>` is not enough to solve your issue.

Comment: I did think about this, I kind of just wanted a return method so that others who may be using this interface know that they can specify the return by looking at the methods that can be called. I think ExecuteAsync<TReturn> could be the best option I have, thank you for the insight.

Comment: Well you can have both `HttpResponseMessage ExecuteAsync()` and `TReturn ExecuteAsync<TReturn>()` and that should give enough info to the users of the API to know what it can do.